# Jquery: if user agent and if width, then

Tags: jquery, css, ipad

An element is acting out on ipad in portrait mode, so trying to set up a custom css for it via  jquery.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
if (isiPad > -1 &&  $(window).width() < 800)
{
$(".fkup").css('margin-top','22px');
}            
});
```

Where did u make a mistake?

Comment: I would suggest using pure CSS instead of Javascript as much as possible. Responsive CSS(incase you are not aware, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)) is the way to go! 
Can you please explain more about what you want?

Comment: I know about media queries. It all works fine except for portrait on ipad, where it goes slightly up.

Comment: You can use the width to determine orientation in media queries. or use media (orientation: landscape)..
By width i mean, say, potrait: media max-width: 320px, landscape: media min-width: 321px. [ This is little tough to generalize though for all tablets. Once you get the ideal px, u can get it ]

Comment: it's ipad only, so user agent must be detected. other tablets work fine. I wish it was that easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use css.. but try this (not tested)

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)/i)) {
    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        $(".fkup").css('margin-top','22px');
    } 
}
```

or the CSS route

```
@media (orientation:landscape) { }
```

Comment: hmm, not up on browser sniffing so try se if this helps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)